# How to drop a specific database using Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

`Mongoid.default_session.database_names` gives me an array of database names. I want to delete a specific database. How would I do that?

`Mongoid.default_session.drop()` always seems to drop the default database even if I override the current database using `Mongoid.override_database("test_database")`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

In Mongoid v2.0.2

```
Mongoid.purge!
```

[Rdoc: Mongoid.purge!](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Config%3apurge!)

Comment: It does nothing in my case!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a combination of `Session.use` and `Session.drop`?

Examples: http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/driver.html